# How make a TPopupmenu transparent?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm adding the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style to the menu window handle in order to make the TPopupMenu transparent but the code is not working, I mean a the menu is not transparent.

This is the code which I'm using

```
var
  hHookID: HHOOK;

function HookCallWndProc(nCode: Integer; wParam, lParam: Longint): Longint; stdcall;
var
  cwps: TCWPStruct;
  lRet: THandle;
  szClass: array[0..256] of char;
  dwNewLong : NativeInt;
begin
  if (nCode = HC_ACTION) then
  begin
    CopyMemory(@cwps, Pointer(lParam), SizeOf(CWPSTRUCT));
    case cwps.message of
      WM_CREATE:
        begin
          GetClassName(cwps.hwnd, szClass, Length(szClass)-1);
          if (lstrcmpi(szClass, '#32768') = 0) then
          begin
                 dwNewLong := GetWindowLongPtr(cwps.hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
                 if (dwNewLong and WS_EX_LAYERED) = 0 then
                 begin
                    SetWindowLongPtr(cwps.hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, dwNewLong or WS_EX_LAYERED);
                    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(cwps.hwnd, 0, 180, LWA_ALPHA);
                 end;

          end;
        end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (hHookID<>0) then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHookID);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  hHookID := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, @HookCallWndProc, 0, GetWindowThreadProcessId(Handle, 0));
end;
```

Any ideas of how make a TPopupmenu transparent or why the above code is not working?

Comment: Please see documentation of `CallNextHookEx`.

Comment: Also, you can directly use `PCWPStruct(lParam)^`, you don't need to make an internal copy.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx()` should be changed to `GetCurrentThreadId()`.

Inside your hook, `WM_CREATE` has not been processed by the window yet, so instead of using `Get/SetWindowLongPtr()`, try adding `WS_EX_LAYERED` to the message's `dwExStyle` field before then calling `CallNextHookEx()` (which you need to fix).  And since the window is still being created and its style has not been applied yet, you will have to delay the call to `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`.

Try this:

```
var
  hHookID: HHOOK = 0;

function HookCallWndProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  cwps: PCWPStruct;
  szClass: array[0..256] of Char;
begin
  if (nCode = HC_ACTION) then
  begin
    cwps := PCWPStruct(lParam);
    case cwps.message of
      WM_CREATE, WM_NCCREATE:
      begin
        GetClassName(cwps.hwnd, szClass, Length(szClass)-1);
        if (lstrcmpi(szClass, '#32768') = 0) then
        begin
          with PCreateStruct(cwps.lParam)^ do
            dwExStyle := dwExStyle or WS_EX_LAYERED;
        end;
      end;
      WM_ACTIVATE:
      begin
        GetClassName(cwps.hwnd, szClass, Length(szClass)-1);
        if (lstrcmpi(szClass, '#32768') = 0) then
          SetLayeredWindowAttributes(cwps.hwnd, 0, 180, LWA_ALPHA);
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(hHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (hHookID<>0) then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHookID);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  hHookID := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, @HookCallWndProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId());
end;
```

With that said, I would suggest using a `WH_CBT` hook instead of manipulating window messages:

```
var
  hHookID: HHOOK = 0;

function HookCBTProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  szClass: array[0..256] of Char;
  dwNewLong: LONG_PTR;
begin
  if (nCode = HCBT_ACTIVATE) then
  begin
    GetClassName(HWND(wParam), szClass, Length(szClass)-1);
    if (lstrcmpi(szClass, '#32768') = 0) then
    begin
      dwNewLong := GetWindowLongPtr(HWND(wParam), GWL_EXSTYLE);
      if (dwNewLong and WS_EX_LAYERED) = 0 then
      begin
        SetWindowLongPtr(HWND(wParam), GWL_EXSTYLE, dwNewLong or WS_EX_LAYERED);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(HWND(wParam), 0, 180, LWA_ALPHA);
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(hHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (hHookID<>0) then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHookID);
end;

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  hHookID := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, @HookCBTProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId());
end;
```

Comment: > *"last parameter of SetWindowsHookEx() should be changed to GetCurrentThreadId()*" > Why? `GetWindowThreadProcessId(Handle, 0)` will retrieve the same Id.

Comment: Thanks but none of the two sample codes is working, for the first sample the `WM_ACTIVATE` is never received for the `#32768` class and for the second sample the `HCBT_ACTIVATE` is never fired for the `#32768` class either.

Comment: @SertacAkyuk: because it is redundant and unnecessary. Accessing the `Handle` creates the HWND in the calling thread (if not already created), so there is no need to create the HWND just to query its thread ID when you can instead query the calling thread ID directly, and let the VCL create the HWND on its own time.

Comment: @Remy - The code in the question is in the `OnCreate` event of the form, the form already has a window handle.

Comment: @Salvador - Try `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` (first snippet). Test for `SWP_SHOWWINDOW` flag, that's the last `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` before the menu window is shown.